# Please assist in explaining this asp.net error message when converting string to datetime

Tags: asp.net, syntax, function, date

**Function:**

```
Public Shared Function ConvertoDate(ByVal dateString As String, ByRef result As DateTime) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim supportedFormats() As String = New String() {"MM/dd/yyyy"}
            result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, supportedFormats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

**Date String**

```
Dim FlightDateArriveString As String = (FlightMonthArrive.SelectedValue.ToString & "/" & FlightDayArrive.SelectedValue.ToString & "/" & "2010")

*ConvertoDate(FlightDateArriveString)*
```

The error message is given by the line above ^ and says:

"Arguement not specified for parameter result of public shared function ConvertoDate (datestring as String, ByRef result as date) as Boolean"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a second parameter to the ConvertoDate function

```
Dim MyResult as DateTime
ConvertoDate(FlightDateArriveString, MyResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting the result?
Your ConvertToDate takes two paramaters: the string to convert, a DateTime reference to place the converted value and returns a boolean to indicate whether it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable to hold the result:

```
Dim result As DateTime
ConvertoDate(FlightDateArriveString, result)
```